# WhatsApp says date and time incorrect on phone

Tags: whatsapp

WhatsApp on my Nokia Lumia 920 says *"Date and time incorrect. Change phone's clock in Settings and restart WhatsApp"*. That does not work.

Comment: Are you sure Date, Time and Region are correct? Have you tried re-installing whatsapp?

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common bugs WhatsApp users face is “Your phone date is inaccurate. Adjust your clock and try again“. If you are experiencing the bug for the first time then here are the simplest solutions for you.

**1. Update WhatsApp:**

80% out of all users affected by this bug (according to our collected data) need to update their WhatsApp version. The bug is caused due to an outdated version of the app.

Back up your messages, Uninstall the app and install it again.

**2. Adjust Date on Your Device:**

If you weren’t able to solve the bug by updating WhatsApp to its latest version, then its possible that date on your device actually needs to be adjusted. Double check and ensure that date and time on your device is correct. If it isn’t adjust it and the error will be fixed.

These two simple solutions will solve the bug for you and you will never see the message saying ‘Your phone date is inaccurate’ again.

Comment: I updated the Whatsapp and updated the date to correct date again, when I go back to Whatsapp it gives the message that Whatsapp is outdated, update it again and we go through the process over and over again with no joy... Please help this is very frustrating...........

Comment: back up the messages and download whatsapp beta , its open to all users now, i'll provide u the link.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/whatsapp/9nblgggzlk1w?tduid=%24adadb2cc2efb8457956cd6c84776ce32%24%24213688%24%242795219%24%24%24%24%24

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is not about WhatsApp being outdated, date not correct, etc. The issue is actually from Windows Phone. If you are experiencing this issue, am sure you are also experiencing a *Microsoft account syncing issue*. Try to sort out your Microsoft account sync issue and everything will be fine.

Comment: Any sugestion for how to sort out a MS account syncing issue?